# AWS Cognito identityID iOS – does it survive system update?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I am using AWS AppSync to connect to the AWS backend, AWS Cognito as a credentials provider and auth management.

Our app needs a feature to be able to connect to the backend with guest authentication, authorised via the IdentityID which you can optain upon the first app launch. The identityID will later be associated with a Cognito UserID if the user decides to register for an account.

Now, the important IdentityID per text device does stay constant in the test and development.

But will it survive a system update on the users device, say from 12.x to 13.x?
Does anyone here have the production experience to confirm it is reliably persisted / identically generated on the device once it was set and associated with a particular device?